# How to modify static text in rdlc file?

Tags: c#, rdlc, rdl

I have a rdlc file and I try to modify a static text on the file, but when I start the program the text in the form is not modified. I use VS C# 2008 Express. What should I do to be able to modify the text in rdlc file?

Comment: Could it be the report file is not being used by the report viewer, but is compiled into the resources? In that case, simply modifying the report file doesn't help. You'd have to recompile the application.

Comment: I compiled the whole solution, but it didn't help, too.

Comment: The main form and the report are different projects and the Reporting.dll is add as reference the main project. I tried also to build the Report and add manualy the new dll to references, but also without nothing to change. I tried to delete the whole content of rdlc file but the report in main project open with old content again. Maybe I missed something between rdlc file and visualization, but I don't know what

Comment: Debug YourReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath to verify exactly which rdlc file is used.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that the main form and the report are in different projects.  You also stated you added the reporting.dll as a reference to the main project.  What MAY be the problem is that you added the actual .DLL of the other project as a reference to the first from "some" location.

In your main solution, did you add your reference and use the tab for "Projects" and pick the project itself? (as opposed to picking a .net library or browse for the physical .dll file.

When you add a reference to the PROJECT, it becomes part of the solution and ultimately part of the building dependency order.  The main project would see the project, force to rebuild it, then take a copy of it's final .dll file and pull it into it's own building folder so it always has "the latest" of the underlying reference .dll.